# Issue in NOT being able to supply HashMap as "value" for a given key in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, xml

I want to use a Hashmap as a value for a key in my applicationContext.xml file.
That is, both the keys and the values for the key that we specify (as given below) would be supplied at runtime ,in the xml file.

```
<beans>
<bean id="movieDetails" class="org.gis.gvb.MovieDetails">
    <property name="name" value="Sri Raghavendra Mahatyam"/>
     <property name="censorRating" value="U"/>
     <property name="userRating" value="*****"/>
      <property name="language" value="Telugu"/>
      <property name="twoD3DND" value="2D"/>
       <property name="releaseYear" value="1986"/>
       <property name="genre" value="Devotional"/>
       <property name="castNCrew" value="Director=Trivikram Srinivas,Producer=Suresh
            Productions,Music=Devisri Prasad,Hero=Venkatesh,Heroine=Katrina Kaif"/>
       </bean>
  </beans>
```

Please help me achieve this.

When tried,I am getting error saying cannot convert from String to HashMap.
Thanks a lot,
Bhaskar Gundu.

Comment: So you want to use a Map as a property for a bean?

Comment: What is reading applicationContext.xml?  As in, what library/framework?  Also, my guess is that you need to use something like a "bean" tag to specify a HashMap, if even it is possible.

Comment: I was looking for help regarding how to use HashMap as a value for a key in applicationContext.xml in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have achieve like this

```
<bean id="movieDetails" class="org.gis.gvb.MovieDetails">
<property name="youMapName">
        <map>
            <entry key="name" value="Sri Raghavendra Mahatyam"/>
            <entry key=="censorRating" value="U"/>
        </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a Map like this first inside your applicationContext.xml:

```
<util:map id="myMap" value-type="java.lang.String">
  <entry key="entry1" value="value1" />
  <entry key="entry2" value="value2" />
  ...
</util:map>
```

Then use this Map in any bean of yours like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.sample.beans">
  <property name="myMap" ref="myMap" />
</bean>
```